# How to get prefix from URL in cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

let say,

URL is : http://localhost/*******/sales/inquiries

Here sale is **prefix** then how can I get this value in controller?

Answer (score 6):

The best way is:

`$this->request->getParam('prefix');`

Others are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Using,

$this->request->params['prefix']

you will get prefix value from URL

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 3.x

```
$this->request->prefix == 'admin'
```